# What does this lean of code mean?

Tags: java

```
capacity = (cap > 0) ? cap : CAPACITY;
```

I'm just looking through my lecture notes, and I can't figure out what this line of code does. Can someone help me?

Comment: lookup ternary conditional expression

Comment: `if (cap > 0) { capacity = cap; } else { capacity = CAPACITY; }`

Comment: it's a ternary operator, and it looks like whoever wrote it was trying to accomplish whether or not to use a default value (CAPACITY). ternary is an "if else" construct

Comment: nice naming of variables btw, `cap`, `capacity` and `CAPACITY` all mean the same thing. That is a sure way to confuse every reader.

Answer (score 0):

It's called [conditional expression](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html) and in your case it means that if cap is greater than 0, the capacity variable will get the value "cap", if false then it will get the value "CAPACITY".